# Is this rvest error due to the website from which I'm trying to scrape?

Tags: r, rvest

I built some code to scrape data from a wrestling data website. Its been 2 1/2 months since I built and ran the code, and running it today, I've gotten errors. I'm simplifying the code for the sake of clarity. For example, when I run

```
awa_history <- "https://www.cagematch.net/?id=5&nr=54"
awa_history_2 <- read_html(awa_history)
```

I get

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Error while processing content unencoding: incorrect data check
```

I have never gotten this error before when I was working on this project a few months ago. I have tried read_html with other websites, and I'm not getting this issue. I've confirmed that the website has not been overhauled from html. I have logged off from my work VPN, and the issue persists.

Does anyone know:
A) if this issue is endemic to this website?
B) if there is anything to do to overcome this issue?

I appreciate any help or thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

No, the website seems to return a response if you wrap the url in `url`:

```
read_html("https://www.cagematch.net/?id=5&nr=54")
#> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
#>   Error while processing content unencoding: incorrect data check

read_html(url("https://www.cagematch.net/?id=5&nr=54"))
#> {html_document}
#> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
#> [1] <head>\n<link href="/2k16/css/2k16.css?20200618" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> ...
#> [2] <body class="TemplateBody">\r\n        <div class="LayoutUserAccount LayoutWidth"> ...
```

Comment: Hey Allan, This seem to work! Question: based on the info I've provided, do you know why it worked before without the url() call, but needs it now? Thanks!

Comment: If you pass a string as a url, `read_html` will create a connection from it using `curl::curl` instead of `url`, and for some reason `curl::curl` throws an error on this particular connection. My best guess is that this is because `curl::curl` now allows non-blocking connections and reads responses as a stream before they have finished downloading. For some reason it is stubbing its toe on decompressing the gzipped stream as it arrives, but the file can unzipped if stored as a local raw vector, which is what `url` does.

Comment: Hey Allan, I appreciate this explanation, and it make perfect sense. Thanks again!